# Word 2000 Displays HTML without any formatting or hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-word, display, html, microsoft-word-2000

I have Microsoft Word 2000 and when I paste HTML code into a word document I loose all the hyperlinks and formatting and get a weird character at the end of each line.

**How can I make Word 2000 display HTML correctly?**

NOTE: I dont see pre-compiled html code when I paste the html into the document(which I copy from a webpage in firefox browser). I see the text(from inside p elements) but hyperlinks aren't shown, the spacing is wrong and theres a funny backwards 'P' character at the end of each line.

Comment: You've got "hidden characters" enabled. Press CTRL+SHIFT+8.

Answer (score 0):

Word 2000 was not initially intended as an HTML editor.  Sure, it came with the ability to "save as web page" which would convert whatever you were working on *into* html.  That's not the same thing as being an HTML editor.  Actually, MS had to issue a filter for MS Word 2000 [HERE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236967) in order to actually "export" what you were working on to standard HTML.

Word 2000 was, at best, supposed to be a WYSIWYG editor... what you see is what you get.  You arrange how you want the web page to look, and when you save (or later Export) it produces the code necessary to support how you wanted it to look.

That backwards P symbol... look up on your tool bar.  You should see one just like it to the immediate left of the Zoom percentage pulldown.  The symbol is called the [Pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow).  It is a paragraph mark.

If you wish to copy HTML and edit it, you would do better with something like Notepad, or even [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which will give you better organization and color coding.  Oh... and either switch to using a more up-to-date [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/) or [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) as both are free and will do more of what you want.